# Plot a raster stack with values above a certain threshold in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-raster

I have a raster stack of 8 TIF images. I am plotting them using the `gplot`. As you can see, the raster values are from 0 to 8, but its impossible to have a place where the pH value of the groundwater is around 0.

1. So, what I want to do is filter the values of the raster files and plot only the regions with pH above 5.
2. Also, I want to label the regions with pH values below 5 in a different color (say, grey) and add a corresponding 'No Data Available' in the legend. Is it possible to do that?

I tried doing something like `pfiles <- pfiles1 > 5` and then plot it. But it throws an error: `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`. I want to use gradient color.

The code I am using:

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
library(viridis)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
shp = broom::tidy(shapefile("G:/WB_dist_utm.shp"))
rfiles = list.files(path = "G:/GW_IDW", pattern = "*.tif", full.names = TRUE)
atr = c(paste("Year", sep = "_", seq(2005, 2019, 2)))

pfiles1 = stack(rfiles[c(33:40)])
names(pfiles) = atr

ph = gplot(pfiles) + 
  geom_raster(aes(fill = value)) +
  geom_path(data=shp, aes(long, lat, group=group), color = 'black') +
  facet_wrap(~ variable, ncol = 4) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(magma(30)), na.value = "transparent", n.breaks = 6) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(), legend.position = "right", legend.direction = "vertical",
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        legend.key.height = unit(2, "cm"), legend.key.width = unit(1, "cm"),
        legend.title = element_blank(), legend.text = element_text(size = 26), 
        strip.text = element_text(size = 28, face = "bold"),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 23, face = "bold"),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 15), plot.caption = element_text(size = 10)) +
  labs(title = "Ground Water Quality in West Bengal: 2005 - 2019",
       subtitle = "pH values\n",
       caption = "Data source: ENVIS Centre on Control of Pollution Water, Air and Noise.
       http://www.cpcbenvis.nic.in/water_quality_data.html
       Prepared by: Akhilesh Kumar") +
  coord_equal()
```

This is the plot I am getting. I want to plot only the pH values > 5 and show the rest of the region in grey with a legend entry as "No Data Available".

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Try with `geom_raster(aes(fill = ifelse(value > 5, value, NA_real_)))`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But no value is getting plotted (and no legend, of course). It's just the shapefiles.